# .Net 7 razor pages routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I added a Terms page in Pages folder like so:

[Pages Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O7SZ.png)

so now I am able to visit the page like https://localhost:7135/Terms.

I have 2 problems.

#1:

Now I want to change the page to terms-and-conditions. How do I do that in .Net 7 razor pages?

I tried this:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {

    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/terms-and-conditions", "Terms");
});
```

But it did not work and browsing to that url gives 404 although /Terms still works which I don't want it to work.

#2: If I change the page name to TermsAndConditions I am unable to browse using https://localhost:7135/TermsAndConditions. Why would that be?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the default route for the page, you can provide an alternative to the `@page` directive at the top of the .cshtml file:

```
@page "/terms-and-conditions"
```

The `AddPageRoute` method is additive in that it won't replace the route generated by the default conventions. The reason your attempt failed to even add the route you wanted is because you have the method parameters to the wrong way round. The relative path to the page file goes first, followed by the route template:

```
AddPageRoute("/Terms", "terms-and-conditions")
```

- https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes
- https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. Could you please let me know answer to my 2nd problem: "If I change the page name to TermsAndConditions in Pages folder I am unable to browse using https://localhost:7135/TermsAndConditions. Why would that be?"

Comment: @KVSharma It should work. You will need to restart the application so that the routes are rebuilt based on any changes to page file names. I don't know why it didn't work for you.